# How to show that $p(x)=(\cos2\pi x,\sin2\pi x)$ is a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

Let $p:(0,1)\to S^1-{(1,0)}$
Defined by
$p(x)=(\cos2\pi x,\sin2\pi x)$

How to show that this map is a homeomorphism?
Note that by $S^1$ I mean a unit circle in $R^2$ and ${(1,0)}$ it's North pole.

Comment: Do you mean $S^1-(1,0)$?

Comment: It's the same thing I want to show that a circle minus one point is homeomorphic to an open interval

Comment: No, it isn't. What is $p(1/4)$ according to your definition?

Comment: Oops! Yes I mean (1,0)

Answer (score 1):

Use $p(x)=e^{2\pi i x}$. Note that $p(0)=p(1)=1$.

Comment: Not sure why you give me this. I want the above function

Comment: It is the same. By Eular's formula : $e^{ix}=\cos x+i \sin x$ or in $\mathbb R^2$ it is equal to $(\cos x, \sin x)$

Comment: Anyways, if you like to use $p(x)=(\cos2\pi x,\sin2\pi x)$, then note that $\cos^22\pi x+ \sin^22\pi x=1$ so it satisfies the circle equation.. and it is periodic. What is the period?

Comment: Oa..  ok I'll try

Answer (score -1):

It is obvious that $p$ is surjective. The distance of $p(x)$ and $p(y)$ is $\sqrt{(cos(2\pi y)-cos(2\pi x))^2+(sin(2\pi y)-sin(2\pi x))^2}=\sqrt{2(1-cos(2\pi x-2\pi y)}$. Note that $-1<x-y<1$ , from $d(p(x),p(y))=0\Leftrightarrow x=y$ and $|x-y|<\epsilon\Leftrightarrow d(p(x),p(y))<\sqrt{2(1-cos(2\pi\epsilon)}$ We know that $p$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: What about the inverse? How to show that it's continuous and before that how to define it.

Comment: In deed we don't need to write the formula of the converse. The first equivalent symble implies that it is invertible. The second symble implies  both of them are continuous.

Comment: Since it is equivalent, we can from left to the right ,and right to the left.

Answer (score -1):

We need to show that the function $P$ is one-to-one, onto, continuous with continuous inverse.

1) Note that for $x,y \in (0,1)$ $$P(x)=P(y) \implies (\cos ( 2\pi x, \sin ( 2\pi x) )= (\cos ( 2\pi y, \sin ( 2\pi y) ) \implies x=y  $$
$
2) If $$(\cos ( 2\pi x), \sin ( 2\pi x) ) \in S^1-(0,1)$ then $0<x<1$

3) Both function $P$ and its inverse function are continuous.

Thus $P$ it is a homeomorphism.